# How to get details for a specific post by user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to get the details for an individual post by the logged in user - specifically, the number of likes it's collected.

Using the Javascript API, I've got a working app ID and can login a user and get their basic info. To get info about a specific object, I think it should be:

```
 FB.api('/1234567890_2345678901', function(response) { ...
```

Where the first part of the number is the user ID and the second part after the underscore is the ID of the post.

However it always returns the same error for every post ID I try:

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID ...  does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
```

I cannot find anything in the docs about getting details for an object. I'm not sure what additional permissions would be needed. The app control panel has no features for adding individual permissions or finding out what they would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to get any data of users who did not authorize your App. If that ID belongs to a post on another users wall, you can´t get access to it. That´s what the error message tells you - you are missing the permission to access it.

Try with an ID that belongs to a post of the currently logged in users wall and it will work. You need the `user_posts` permission, of course. For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: That's what I was trying - I logged in myself and tried to get details for one of my own posts, however I cannot. What permission does the app need to requiest? I don't see a way to request permissions in the app dashboard.

Comment: it´s user_posts. use FB.login with the scope parameter.

Comment: i have added a link to an article about login and stuff

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. One other thing - is there a way to get details for a specific, public post from a public page? (Not a user post, a page post.)

Comment: sure, for that you just need any access token. there´s no other difference, just use the correct id.